# Set the OS X clipboard to a rich text link in a Ruby or shell script

Tags: macos, ruby, hyperlink, iwork

I'm trying to generate a report by using a Ruby script to parse an XML document. I'm pulling link text and the actual URL and I'd like to be able to format those in a way that I could simply copy/paste the results into Pages/Numbers and have the hyperlink with correct link text immediately set. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

`echo -En '<a href="http://t.co">tco</a><br><a href="http://g.co">gco</a>' | textutil -format html -convert rtf -stdin -stdout | pbcopy -Prefer rtf`

The output will always include styles. For some reason `pbcopy -Prefer rtf` doesn't include a plain text version on the clipboard so you won't be able to paste anything in plain text views.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy / paste a link with a descriptive text different from the URL into Pages, the OS X pasteboard needs to contain an URL object (not plain text or HTML). In Ruby, you can create such a URL pasteboard object using the [*pasteboard* gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/pasteboard) (`gem install pasteboard`) and the following code:

```
require 'pasteboard'
pasteboard = Pasteboard.new
pasteboard.put_url '<link URL>', '<link text>'
```

See the [gem documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pasteboard/1.0/frames), where I lifted this example wholesale.